# Android drag and drop the view in view container so that the views should swipe each other

Tags: android

I am using viewconatiner in that i am dispalying some images having different height and width. when i drag and drop the the views should swipe, is it possible to swipe the view when i drag and drop. can any one please help?

```
    // Drag enterd
     if (e.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
                    if (container.getContainerType() ==     VContainer.Level.EXC.getLevelCode()) {
                        container.getVContainer().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        return incEXCViewSpace(container);
                    } else if (container.getContainerType() == VContainer.Level.LRLINE.getLevelCode()) {
                        container.getVContainer().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        return incLRViewSpace(container);
                    }
                    Log.d("MOVEDRAG ", " -- drag entered " + container.getContainerType());
                }

//drag end
else if (e.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
                    try {
                        storyToolBarLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                PrintO.log("ACTION_DRAG_ENDED InsideRun");
                                storyToolBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                showFooterMenuLayout(true);
                            }
                        });

//                    storyToolBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //hideAllTranspViews();
                        v1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    catch(Exception f) {
                        f.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

please go through it.

Comment: add what you have done so far

Comment: Added Code please go through it.